# How does thrift define nested structs?

Tags: thrift

For example, how to define the following structure。

```
struct Model {
    1:list<Model> models;
}
```

Such a structure compiler will report an error
[Type "Model" has not been defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpNdH.png)

Comment: Show us the error please.

Answer (score 1):

Works perfectly, given you use a recent version, see [THRIFT-2421](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2421)

```
$ ./thrift-0.9.1 -version
Thrift version 0.9.1

$ ./thrift-0.9.1 -gen cpp ./test.thrift
[ERROR:test.thrift:2] (last token was 'Model')
Type "Model" has not been defined.

$ ./thrift-0.10.0 -version
Thrift version 0.10.0

$ ./thrift-0.10.0 -gen cpp ./test.thrift

$
```

PS: Most recent version at the time of writing is 0.14.1.